# style does not apply correctly into a liferay jsp

Tags: css, jsp, liferay-6

I would like to know why if I run this code into a browser (I just write it into a new local jsp file and run it into a browser):

```
<style>
  .rounded_control {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #e00;
    color=#e00;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" class="rounded_control"></textarea>
```

The style is correctly applied. But if I run this code on a liferay server JSP page, the style does not apply.

PS: The style is ugly and stupid, this is just for test purpose of course :)

Comment: Try changing `color=` to `color:`.

Comment: You should provide more information if it is not theoretical but practice question.

Comment: this is not the problem, iven if I only set .rounded_control {
 border-radius: 6px;} , it does not apply in second case.

Comment: How and into which Liferay-JSP did you include the snippet? And can you check how the generated HTML looks like in the browser?

Comment: for test purpose, I only copy-pasted the mentionned code into my view.jsp. This is a liferay portlet artifact so this jsp is immediately called when the portlet is invoked.

Comment: I just edited my post as the code was missing the last line explaining how I test the class

Comment: @Manoj The `<style>` tag is more important than the _Run code snippet_ feature - this is not a question about the correct CSS styles - no one needs to see how this looks like.

Comment: @A.D. What about the generated HTML? Is it different? And I usually add the CSS into its own file and reference that one in `<header-portlet-css>` in `liferay-portlet.xml` - although I would expect that the inlined styles work as well.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Got it. Reverted back.